# force applied to a pole afloat

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, physics, rotations

So I've been attempting to simulate the movement of a boat afloat when a force is applied to it, such as an oar stroke or a current. For the sake of this question I've simplified it down to the **following scenario:**

A pole sits afloat on a still body of water. The coordinates of its centre of gravity (A) is known, as well as the coordinates at the point on the pole where the force is applied (B) and the vector of the force (c). The force can be applied in any direction at point (B).

*How do I calculate the turning force at point (A) and the movement vector of point (A)?*

*This relates to my boat scenario* in that (A) is the centre of gravity of the boat, there will be multiple points (B) that determine the force acting upon them and the resulting rotation and translation forces will be summed up and applied to the boat over a given timeframe (T).

I understand there will be additional complexities to my boat scenario, if you have input on this it will also be appreciated however I phrased the question in relation to a generic pole with a single force acting upon it to make the answer more applicable to others with similar questions.

Thanks for considering my question.

Comment: So basically the boat can only move in 2 dimensions? One part is physics working out the angular momentum. The other part such that what you want is a linear transformation.

Comment: @marshalcraft Yep, it's on a two dimensional plain, (Top down).